# What is the difference between = and |= in C?

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I'm new to C and I am trying to understand the difference between

```
DDRB |= 0b00000001;
```

and

```
DDRB = 0b00000001;
```

Do the two lines have same effect of writing one to data register B ?

How are they different?

Just could register google search for "|" ..so needed some help in understanding it.

Comment: These are called "operators", that will help you search. In short, `=` assigns the value, in this case a single bit, and any previous value of `DDRB` is lost. `|=` modifies the value by taking the original value of `DDRB`, and then setting that specific bit while leaving all other bits in `DDRB` unmodified.

Comment: I think you should read a C book. You will struggle if you do not learn the basics of the language you use

Comment: Ultimately, this is fundamental and you would do better consulting a C reference text that asking such questions on SO - that will be a very slow way of learning if you have to ask abut each fundamental language feature (and will not help your SO rep).  I am guessing you have seen this somewhere in existing code and lack a good reference or resource to recognise it.  All available C operators including these (`=` assignment, and `|=` bitwise OR-assignment) are summarised at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.

Comment: A more complete treatment of the operators can be found  in many places such as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Comment: If you _are_ trying to learn form existing code or projects without learning the fundamentals from a good reference, _caution_; that tends to lead to _Cargo Cult Programming_, and you are yet ill-equipped to tell the difference between bad code and good (and a lot of "found" code is pretty grim IMO).

Comment: I need to start reading a good C Language guide

Comment: Read a book or online tutorial.  This is no place for such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the two lines have same effect of writing one to data register B ?

No.

```
DDRB = 0b00000001;
```

writes one to bit-0 and zero to bits 1 to 7, while:

```
DDRB |= 0b00000001;
```

is a read-modify-write operation equivalent to:

```
DDRB = DDRB | 0b00000001;
```

so it writes a one to bit-0 as before and leaves all other bits unchanged.

So for example if `DDRB`'s current value were `0b11110000` after:

```
DDRB = 0b00000001;
```

it will be `0b00000001` while after:

```
DDRB |= 0b00000001;
```

it will be `0b11110001`.

So one sets DDRB to 1, while the other sets DDRB:Bit-0 to 1.

Answer (score 4):

The first operation is called [bitwise OR |](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) and it works as follows imagining the numbers A=200 and B=184, which in binary will be, 11001000 and 10111000, respectively. The operator "|" will compare bit a bit of each of those numbers, and returns 1 when either of the bits is `1`, `0` otherwise. So in your case:

```
  11001000  
| 10111000 
  -------- 
= 11111000
```

the result will be 248 (11111000 in binary). Therefore `DDRB |= 0b00000001;` is DDRB = DDRB | 0b00000001.

The second operation (*e.g.,* `DDRB = 0b00000001`) is just an assignment of a value to a variable.